# How to use join in a case statement

Tags: sql, case

Code below is not working. I want to pull the BatchHorizon of the corresponding PACKAGE. I cannot directly use "then BatchHorizon " since the batchhorizon is inside the subquery.

```
Case When PACKAGE IN (SELECT DISTINCT PACKAGE
                      FROM BATCHINGWINDOW AS A
                     ) 
     Then (SELECT  BatchHorizon
           FROM BATCHINGWINDOW AS B 
           WHERE B.PACKAGE = A.PACKAGE
         )
     else 3
 end
```

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement. (It has a return value...)

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Please edit your question and explain.  You should provide sample data and desired results, so we know what you are attempted to accomplish.

Comment: could you please provide samples of your input and desired outputs in order to better understand your needs?

Comment: That's not a good way to try and do things. I'd rethink my approach as it seems like you're trying to make a procedure that does a lot of different things (one-size-fits-all) instead of making specialized queries which you can optimize much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 

Case When O.PACKAGE IN (SELECT PACKAGE
                      FROM BATCHINGWINDOW  
                     ) 
     Then (SELECT  DISTINCT BatchHorizon
           FROM BATCHINGWINDOW AS B 
           WHERE B.PACKAGE = O.PACKAGE
         )
     else 3
 end pack
 from table O
```